# Matching d3.js geo projection with pyproj Proj4

Tags: coordinate-system, d3, pyproj

I am having trouble figuring out the correct notation for Proj4 projections with pyproj. I got the following projection in d3.js and I want to match it with pyproj on my backend to send a background bitmap for the map.

```
var projection = d3.geo.albers()
    .center([0, 55.4])
    .rotate([4.4, 0])
    .parallels([50, 60])
    .scale(4800)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

Here is what it looks like:
[image]

The points I need to project onto this are lat, lng.

```
 toP = pyproj.Proj("+proj=aea ... ? ")
 x, y = pyproj.transform(EPSG4326, toP, x, y)
```

Comment: Have you looked at your JSON file? If you are lucky, it [might tell you the CRS](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#named-crs).

Comment: the data I need to project is based on raw lat lng, basically a bunch of sensor points I loop through an create a gridded interpolated map. I want to underlay the map on the above projection as a bitmap by applying the same projection as I did in my frontend.

Comment: See: http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/albers_equal_area_conic.html
You can probably set up the parallels and center, however you will still have some transformation to do for the scale and rotation

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://bl.ocks.org/armollica/e6371dcceed6d89312cf6a78be1a0b49